# php soap webservices not working on server

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I was using php webservice. A service call returning value when I am using it separately only one then, but when I am using it with multiple function it is calling but not returning value. the single wsdl is like : for MessageRS()

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='utf-8' ?>
<definitions name='shop'
  targetNamespace='http://localhost/soap/'
  xmlns:tns='http://localhost/soap/'
  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
  xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

    <message name='messageRQ'>
    <part name='sendXML' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>
  <message name='messageRS'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>

  <portType name='CatalogPortType'>

  <operation name='MessageRS'>
        <input message='tns:messageRQ'/>
        <output message='tns:messageRS'/>
    </operation>

    </portType>

    <binding name='CatalogBinding' type='tns:CatalogPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>

    <operation name='MessageRS'>
        <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#MessageRS'/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name='CatalogService'>
    <port name='CatalogPort' binding='CatalogBinding'>
      <soap:address location='http://1mp1.viewthedemo.com/s/server/server.php'/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

and when using with

```
<message name='getCatalogRequest'>
    <part name='catalogId' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>
  <message name='getCatalogResponse'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>

  <message name='manufacturerRQ'>
    <part name='manufacturerRQxml' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>
  <message name='mamufacturerRS'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>

  <message name='messageRQ'>
    <part name='sendXML' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>
  <message name='messageRS'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>

  <message name='saveRQ'>
    <part name='SaveRQParameter' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>
  <message name='saveRS'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>

  <message name='Product_list'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>

  <message name='SettingRQ'>
    <part name='xml' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>
  <message name='SettingRS'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
  </message>





  <portType name='CatalogPortType'>
    <operation name='getCatalogEntry'>
      <input message='tns:getCatalogRequest'/>
      <output message='tns:getCatalogResponse'/>
    </operation>
    <operation name='ManufacturerRS'>
      <input message='tns:manufacturerRQ'/>
      <output message='tns:mamufacturerRS'/> 
     </operation>
    <operation name='MessageRS'>
        <input message='tns:messageRQ'/>
        <output message='tns:messageRS'/>
    </operation>

    <operation name='SaveRS'>
      <input message='tns:saveRQ'/>
      <output message='tns:saveRS'/>
    </operation>
    <operation name='Product_list'>
      <input message='tns:Product_list'/>
      <output message='tns:Product_list'/>
    </operation>
    <operation name='SettingRS'>
      <input message='tns:SettingRQ'/>
      <output message='tns:SettingRS'/>
    </operation>


  </portType>

  <binding name='CatalogBinding' type='tns:CatalogPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
    <operation name='getCatalogEntry'>
      <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#getCatalogEntry'/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </output>
    </operation>

    <operation name='ManufacturerRS'>
      <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#ManufacturerRS'/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </output>
    </operation>

    <operation name='MessageRS'>
        <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#MessageRS'/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </output>
    </operation>

    <operation name='SaveRS'>
      <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#SaveRS'/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </output>
    </operation>

    <operation name='Product_list'>
      <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#Product_list'/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </output>
    </operation>

    <operation name='SettingRS'>
      <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#Product_list'/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
      </output>
    </operation>
```

Then it is not sending value in the client page.

Comment: What errors do you get? What is the server and your localhost OS version?

Comment: Might also want to look at mime-types.

Answer (score 0):

I guess first you need to check if soap extension is enabled or not on the server.you can check soap extension using phpinfo().

Comment: my localhost PHP Version 5.3.5 and the the server PHP Version 5.2.17